# How can I disable tap-to-click on Apple Magic Trackpad?

Tags: touchpad, hardware, input-devices

Apple Magic Trackpad uses bluetooth and does a tap-to-click function. I hate that because I don't like accidental clicking. I want to only click with a real press. I can't figure out how to turn it off. Tap to click is off in my main settings already.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what release of Ubuntu (and/or flavor) this relates to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu 18.04 or higher you should be able to enable/disable this feature by using `gnome-tweak-tool`. If you need to install the `gnome-tweak-tool`, you could do that through the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then run `tweaks`, navigate to the `Keyboard & Mouse`-section. Under the `Touchpad/Mouse Click Emulation` headline select `disabled`.